# C# - How to close current window and get new window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm implementing a window form  in C#. I want to close current window and open a new window. (Just like File->New function in applications)

This is my code

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        Image_Editor IE = new Image_Editor(); //Image_Editor is the name of window
        IE.Show();
        this.Close();
        
    }
```

Images of what I want to achieve:

[image]
<sub>(source: [infosight.com](http://www.infosight.com/labelaseproducer/images/designfilemenu.jpg))</sub>

[image]

I want to implement the "new" function as shown in the above link. When executing given code, new window just appeared and both windows close at the same time.

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: This is a very bad formulated question. How do you expect us to help you if you do not show any code at all? If you want help, you need to tell what are you trying to do (with enough details), the action and the expected result, show the code you are using or tried, and the error you get (the difference between the expected result and the result you get with your code). At minimum...

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want to close this windows and open a windows like your current windows use this

```
Myform frm; //thats name of the class of your form like Form1
frm = new Myform();
frm.Show(); // show the secend one
this.Close(); // and close the first one
```